# How to ensure Async.StartChild is started before continuing?

Tags: asynchronous, f#, async-await

I am trying to await an event with timeout. I am abstracting this behind a function `startAwaitEventWithTimeout`. Currently my code looks like this (including some debug output messages):

```
let startAwaitEventWithTimeout timeoutMs event =
  async {
    Console.WriteLine("Starting AwaitEvent in eventAwaiter")
    let! eventWaiter = Async.StartChild(Async.AwaitEvent event, timeoutMs)
    try
      Console.WriteLine("Awaiting event in eventAwaiter")
      let! res = eventWaiter
      return Ok res
    with :? TimeoutException ->
      return Error ()
  } |> Async.StartChild
```

Here's a test:

```
let testEvent = Event<string>()

[<EntryPoint>]
let run _ =
  async {
    Console.WriteLine("Starting event awaiter in main")
    let! eventAwaiter = testEvent.Publish |> startAwaitEventWithTimeout 1000

    Console.WriteLine("Triggering event")
    testEvent.Trigger "foo"
    Console.WriteLine("Awaiting event awaiter in main")
    let! result = eventAwaiter

    match result with
    | Ok str -> Console.WriteLine("ok: " + str)
    | Error () -> Console.WriteLine("TIMEOUT")
  } |> Async.RunSynchronously
  0
```

Unfortunately, even though everything is "awaited" as far as I can see, it seems the `run` function proceeds to triggering the event before `Async.AwaitEvent` has had a chance to subscribe to the event. In short, here is the output I get:

```
Starting event awaiter in main
Starting AwaitEvent in eventAwaiter
Triggering event
Awaiting event awaiter in main
Awaiting event in eventAwaiter
TIMEOUT
```

Here is what I would expect:

```
Starting event awaiter in main
Starting AwaitEvent in eventAwaiter
Awaiting event in eventAwaiter  <-- this is moved up
Triggering event
Awaiting event awaiter in main
ok foo
```

I can work around the problem by adding e.g. `do! Async.Sleep 100` between calling `startAwaitEventWithTimeout` and triggering the event, but of course this is less than ideal.

Have I done something incorrectly, and is there any way I can reliably ensure that `AwaitEvent` has been called before I trigger the event?

(Side note: I am doing this because we are calling remote processes over TCP, and all communication from the remote is done via events.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably I am missing some requirement but your code can easily be refactored using continuations and the error fixed by itself.

```
let testEvent = Event<unit>()

let run _ =
  let ts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(float 1))
  let rc r =  Console.WriteLine("ok")
  let ec _ =  Console.WriteLine("exception")
  let cc _ =  Console.WriteLine("cancelled")
  Async.StartWithContinuations((Async.AwaitEvent testEvent.Publish), rc , ec,  cc, ts.Token  )
  testEvent.Trigger()
run()
```

Edit: If you have a specific requirement to use async workflows, you can convert it by using TaskCompletionSource in TPL.

```
let registerListener  timeout event= 
  let tcs = TaskCompletionSource()
  let ts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout))
  let er _ =  tcs.SetResult (Error())
  Async.StartWithContinuations(Async.AwaitEvent event, tcs.SetResult << Ok , er , er , ts.Token)
  Async.AwaitTask tcs.Task

let run _ =
  let testEvent = Event<int>()
  async {
       let listener = registerListener (float 1) testEvent.Publish
       testEvent.Trigger 2
       let! ta  = listener 
       match ta with
         | Ok n -> printfn "ok: %d" n
         | Error () -> printfn "error"
  } |> Async.RunSynchronously

run()
```

Note that even though it is far easier to understand than spawning/awaiting multiple child computations, most of this code is still boilerplate and I am sure there must far easier solutions for setting a simple timeout value.

Comment: I need to get the value the event was triggered with, whereas `StartWithContinuations` returns `unit`. I slightly modified the code in the question to make this clearer.

Comment: @cmeeren You can use the `rc` callback to get the value of the event. Do you have any more requirements?

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to integrate this into the existing code. Say I have an async CE where I want to first set up an event awaiter, then trigger an operation that results in the event being fired at some point, and then return the event value to the calling code (which is also `async`, of course) wrapped in `Result` (where `Error ()` indicates timeout).

Comment: @cmeeren you can convert it by using TaskCompletionSource but i am sure there are better ways to do this. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that you experience a race condition because you are consistently firing the event before the child computation is even started. Let's change the set-up - like you did for testing - to include a delay before firing.

```
open System
open System.Threading

let e = Event<_>()

let sleeper timeToFire = async{
    do! Async.Sleep timeToFire
    e.Trigger() }

let waiter = async{
    do! Async.AwaitEvent e.Publish
    return Ok() }

let foo timeToFire timeOut = async{
    Async.Start(sleeper timeToFire)
    let! child = Async.StartChild(waiter, timeOut)
    try return! child
    with :? TimeoutException -> return Error() }

foo 500 1000 |> Async.RunSynchronously
// val it : Result<unit,unit> = Ok null
foo 1000 500 |> Async.RunSynchronously
// val it : Result<unit,unit> = Error null
```

A race condition will now appear if the delay to firing is equal to the timeout.

Comment: "Race condition" might have been the wrong term given my test code. In our system, the event is of course not triggered immediately from the same thread, but remotely from other threads. The local thread triggers a remote operation that will result in an event being raised at some point, possibly almost immediately, which causes the problem. I have clarified the title now.